# Hoisting inside function - inner function and variable having same name - Output?

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

```js
function y() {
  var x = 'hi';

  function x() {
    return 'bye';
  };
  return x(); // x is not a function
  return x; // 'hi'
}

console.log(y())
```

Not able to get this function execution. Can someone explain?

Comment: Your variable name and function name are the same.
Changing either of those should fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function and variable declarations are hoisted.  Function declarations also hoist the assignment of the value.

So both `function x` and `var x` create a variable named `x` in the current scope. `function x` also assigns a function to that variable.

Assignments with `=` are not hoisted.

So `x = 'hi'` overwrites that function with a string.